# How to generate a n-dimensional "identity matrix"?

Tags: functional-programming, python-3.x

I'm building a demonstration any-dimensional `Vector` class to show some functional programming in Python.

```
class Vector():
  def __init__(self, *coords):
    self.coords = coords
  def __add__(this, that):
    return Point(*[(x+y) for x,y in zip(this.coords, that.coords)])
  #...
```

While trying to come up with an example of a static `@classmethod` in this example, I decided it'd be nice to have a class method giving me an n-dimensional base of vectors for any `n`. That is:

```
>>> Vector.get_base(dimensions = 2)
[Vector(1,0), Vector(0,1)]
>>> Vector.get_base(3)
[Vector(1,0,0), Vector(0,1,0), Vector(0,0,1)]
>>> Vector.get_base(1)
[Vector(1)]
```

I'm however having a huge brain fart however and am stumbling on the problem of how to "properly" generate those lists.

What I can think up right now is a declarative solution:

```
def get_base(dimensions):
  arrays = []
  zeros = [0] * dimensions
  for i in range(dimensions):
    item = zeros
    item[i] = 1
    arrays.append(Vector(*array))
  return arrays
```

There has to be a better way! How can I rewrite this function in a hopefully more concise or Pythonic functional style?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could do this:

```
def get_base(dimensions):
    return [Vector(*coords) for coords in 
        [[(0,1)[i==j] for i in range(dimensions)] for j in range(dimensions)]]
```

but I would break it down a little:

```
def get_base(dimensions):
    arrays = [[(0,1)[i==j] for i in range(dimensions)] for j in range(dimensions)]
    return [Vector(*coords) for coords in arrays]
```

Which is a *little* better.  Remember, not everything has to be a one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

How about the next:

```
>>> def get_base(dimensions):
...     for points in set(itertools.permutations([0] * (dimensions - 1) + [1], dimensions)):
...             yield Vector(*points)
```